# Install Bootstrap in my Ruby on Rails project using bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2, bootstrap-sass

I am new to Rails. I wanted to use bootstrap so I have placed the 'bootstrap-sass' as in it's documentation in my Gemfile  like the following:

```
group :assets do
 gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
 gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
 gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
 gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.3.1.0'
end
```

and I tried to install it using 'bundle install', which gave me the following error message:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https,//rubygems.org/"...........
Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler troubleshooting documentation at
http://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks!

/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/config_file.rb:195:in `merge': can't convert String into Hash (TypeError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/config_file.rb:195:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:364:in `new'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:364:in `configuration'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:34:in `configuration'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:53:in `sources='
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:249:in `remote_specs'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:162:in `fetch_specs'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:66:in `specs'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:192:in `block (2 levels) in index'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:189:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:189:in `block in index'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/index.rb:9:in `build'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:185:in `index'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:179:in `resolve'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:114:in `specs'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:109:in `resolve_remotely!'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/installer.rb:83:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/installer.rb:14:in `install'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/cli.rb:247:in `install'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:27:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_task'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:344:in `dispatch'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:434:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.3.4/bin/bundle:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:3:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.3.4/bin/bundle:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/bundle:19:in `<main>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Comment: try `gem update bundler`. And follow the steps that you were doing.

Comment: did rails ever worked in your system? If not, how did you install it?

Comment: Did you really get a COMMA in `https,//rubygems.org`? That's messed up.

Comment: can we see the whole of your Gemfile? I wonder if there's something in there that might be adding the comma to your source

Answer (score 0):

Your error message is messed up, but there seems to be a problem with bundler.

If not, quick and dirty: Use [the twitter-bootstrap-rails gem](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails). It will work for sure.

Comment: After struggling for hours I found out a simple solution for it. I have set my .gemrc file as 'install --no-rdoc --no-ri'
'update --no-rdoc --no-ri'. I just deleted these two items then tried to install. Bingo! It works!.. After it is installed, I put back the code I deleted in the .gemrc file